# What exactly is (nil) doing in this context []string(nil)

Tags: go

I was looking at the Slice Tricks: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

and I noticed in their copy example they have `[]T(nil)`

I haven't seen `(nil)` like this before and I can't find any documentation on using it or what exactly it accomplishes (I know it's self explanatory but I want to know how it acts the same as `make` or `[]string{}`

the only reference I can find by googling "golang (nil) slice" is

> Since the zero value of a slice (nil) acts like a zero-length slice, you can declare a slice variable and then append to it in a loop:

But it doesn't say where it can be used or exactly what it accomplishes, like can I use this with structs or whatever I want?

e.g.:

package main

import "log"

```
func main() {
    str := []string{"Hello", "Bye", "Good Day", "????????"}
    cop := append([]string(nil), str...)    

    log.Println(str)
    log.Println(cop)
}
```

I'm strictly only curious about how `(nil)` operates, and what it can operate on.

Like does

```
[]string(nil)
```

Operate the same as

```
[]string{}
```

or what is the difference here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a type conversion, converting a `nil` to a slice.

These are equivalent

```
var t []string
t := []string(nil)
```

In both cases, `t` is of type `[]string`, and `t == nil`

Comment: So is this at all similar to doing `interfaceType.(string)`? Also would it operate the same as `[]string{}`?

Comment: No. The `.(type)` is a "type assertion". The `[]string{}` syntax allocates a slice, and isn't `nil`.

Comment: So what would the benefit of using `[]string(nil)` over `[]string{}` in the append example be?

Comment: the latter requires an allocation.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I see it now in a different light, it would be the same as `uint64(2)` for some reason I just couldn't see it with it being wrapped around a `nil` and being `[]string()`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
list := []string(nil) // list is an empty slice of strings
```

`func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type`

function takes a slice of strings and a variable length list of strings, and returns a slice where the list of strings is appended to the end.

so:

```
cop := append([]string(nil), str...)
```

will create an empty slice of strings and append the strings in "str" and return the result.

This the result slice is a copy, because it has all of the same values in the same order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm aware of how append works, I'm strictly talking about `[]string(nil)` its self, I'm curious how `(nil)` operates and what it can operate on, the append was just an example, I'm wondering if there's any benefit over using `[]string{}` or `[]string(nil)`